# Setting a spherical area in a BufferedImage to be a certain opacity efficently

Tags: java, bufferedimage, isometric

first of all I have scoured Google and SO for this answer, finding only how to change the actual pixels to be of a certain alpha value, which would be incredibly slow or actually making a part of the `BufferedImage` *completely* transparent via the use of `lwg2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR))`. This is the exact functionality I need, however, I need to have the value to be less than `1f`, which you cannot do with this specific instance of `AlphaComposite.CLEAR`.

What I want this implementation for is to make a wall inside my 2.5d game become transparent when the player goes behind it, like so: [image: example]

The logic behind my game is that the terrain is one `BufferedImage` which is only updated when called, and then having the rest of the walls, etc, being drawn onto another `BufferedImage` where entities are also drawn, so the opacity transformation would only affect the trees (or walls).

This is the code I am using atm, but as I said I don't want the circle that I am drawing to make a part of the image completely transparent, but only slightly (about 50%):

```
g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR, 0.5f));
g2.fillOval(x - (int) (TILE_WIDTH * 1), y - (int) (TILE_HEIGHT * 1.5), TILE_WIDTH * 2, TILE_HEIGHT * 3);
```

(The `0.5f` in the `AlphaComposite` constructor does nothing).

The reason I need this to be efficient is because I am updating this image 30 times a second, so efficiency > quality.

Comment: `finding only how to change the actual pixels to be of a certain alpha value, which would be incredibly slow`.

Maybe you can use this method at start up to store a translucent version of each sprite you draw in game, that way you don't suffer the overhead per frame.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove yes, I thought of doing it that way, but say I have a tile with walls that extend to the z=10 range at the coordinates (player.x, player.y - 10)? This will mean that I will have to check all of the tiles below the player in the y axis, then set the translucent images at the specific z axis (not that hard, but still not that efficient since i'd have to iterate over a lot of tiles and walls, considering each wall has it's own object). It is a good approach but has it's restrictions as the game has an infinite z axis and since it is isometric. Thanks though.

Comment: You can define Shape (spherical) and set clip for the graphics (to repaint only requested area), and fill it with semi transparent color (white for example)

Comment: Since you have a grid system, things could be easier to implement. Use your grid to determine the tile "infront" of your character. Make the bufferedImage on these tiles translucent. When your character move behind certain tiles, only redraw those tiles and make them translucent. When your character move out, repaint it to normal. Set translucent by setting the alpha value on the single bufferedimage won't be too costly.

Comment: @user3437460 I ended up doing just that, though I had to hack around due to the reason mentioned in the comment reply to NESPowerGlove. My fps did take a hit, but then again I am running this on a rPi ;).

Comment: @nyxaria Ah yes, that is one alternative too. Prepare the translucent images before hand. That will help a little. But I think, most importantly is to come out with an efficient paint mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up solving the issue by not manipulating the image directly via making a part of the image translucent, but manipulating the opacity of the images I am drawing with. As @user343760 and @NESPowerGlove mentioned, I could just make the assets I am using translucent when the player is behind it. Since I am using a underlying grid array to back my game, I could do this by working out if the `tile.x - 1 == (int) player.x` and `tile.y - 1== (int) player.y`. In isometry, this meant that the player was on the tile directly above it in our perspective. Then I had to solve the issue if the wall.z is bigger than 0 or 1, hence having the problem where a tile 5 blocks "bellow" the player could obstruct him if the walls extended z = 5 above the tile. For this problem, I implemented the following solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < wall.getAsset(1f).getHeight()/TILE_HEIGHT; i++) {
    if((tile.x - i - wall.z == (int) world.player.getX() && tile.y - i -wall.z == (int) world.player.getY())) {
        lwg2.drawImage(wall.getAsset(0.5f), x, y, this);                                            
    }
}
```

This also ensures that the image is transparent even if the player is "above" the tile "above" the tile where the wall is situated, in terms of the image extending above that limit. I have fixed this via using the for loop which looks above for `i` number of times, depending on the `image.height/tile_height`, which is an universal constant.

If you require to make a part of the image transparent, I have not found solutions which would work fault free, except for manipulating the pixels in the low-levels of `BufferedImage`. If you also want to erase a part of an image directly, use the code `g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));` and draw as you would normally. Remember to switch back to a normal composite via `g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));`.

You could also draw with a certain opacity in the first place using the `Composite` `g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity));`, where `opacity` is a `float` with values from `0f` to `1f`, `0f` being completely transparent and `1f` being completely opaque.

I hope this helped anyone out there. If you find a better way of doing this, please leave a comment for future readers.

This is what my solution looks like :):

[image: working example]